# How can I move each bxSlider slider from opposite side?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using three bxSlider based slider. I want to move each slider from opposite side. I have tried and done it for first two round but in the end of second round slide starting to move from same direction of previous slide.

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ysL75mev/) is all script which I have tried so far.

I am sorry if the question is not clear, kindly check the fiddle so that you will understand about my issue and thank you in advance for that.

Below is the main script, which is I am trying

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

let slideOneFirstInterval       = true;
let slideTwoFirstInterval       = true;
let slideThreeFirstInterval     = true; 

let slideOne  = $('#owlSlide1');

slideOne.bxSlider({
    auto            : false,
    autoControls    : false,
    stopAutoOnClick : false,
    pager           : false,
    speed           : 2000,
    infiniteLoop    : true,
    responsive      : true,
    slideWidth      : 600,
    controls        : false,
    autoStart       : false,
    randomStart     : false,
    preloadImages   :'all',
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        if (slideThreeFirstInterval) {

            setTimeout(function() { 
                //slideTwo.goToNextSlide(); 
                slideThree.goToNextSlide();
                console.log('True Statement.. 1');
            }, 2000);
            slideThreeFirstInterval = false

        } else {


            setTimeout(function() { 
                slideThree.goToPrevSlide(); 
                console.log('False Statement.. 1');
            }, 2000);
        }

    },

    autoDelay : 0,

});

let slideTwo  = $('#owlSlide2');
slideTwo.bxSlider({
    auto            : false,
    autoControls    : false,
    stopAutoOnClick : false,
    pager           : false,
    speed           : 2000,
    infiniteLoop    : true,
    responsive      : true,
    slideWidth      : 600,
    controls        : false,
    autoStart       : true,
    randomStart     : false,
    preloadImages   :'all',
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {

        if (slideTwoFirstInterval) {

            setTimeout(function() { 
                //slideThree.goToNextSlide();
                slideOne.goToPrevSlide();
                console.log('True Statement.. 2');

            }, 2000);
            slideTwoFirstInterval = false
        } else {

            setTimeout(function() { 
                //slideThree.goToNextSlide();
                slideOne.goToPrevSlide();
                console.log('false Statement.. 2');

            }, 2000);
        }

    },
});

let slideThree = $('#owlSlide3')

slideThree.bxSlider({
    auto            : false,
    autoControls    : false,
    stopAutoOnClick : false,
    pager           : false,
    speed           : 2000,
    infiniteLoop    : true,
    responsive      : true,
    slideWidth      : 600,
    controls        : false,
    autoStart       : true,
    randomStart     : false,
    autoDelay       : 0,
    preloadImages   :'all',

    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            //slideOne.goToNextSlide();
            slideTwo.goToPrevSlide();
            console.log('True Statement.. 3');
        }, 2000);

    },
});

setTimeout(function() { 
    //slideOne.goToNextSlide();
    slideTwo.goToNextSlide();
    console.log('false Statement.. 3');
}, 3000);
```

});

Comment: It's way too much code. 1st: remove the div onclick's for the demo (they're really annoying and they do not help debugging - on the contrary). 2nd: remove the sliders that work properly, and only leave the one that doesn't. 3rd. remove everything that's not needed for viewing the bug. If it can be reproduced with everything else deleted and only 2 slides, perfect. We don't need to know/see it's inside a third of your layout. It's irrelevant.

Comment: To make it clear: **anyone** trying to fix your bug will do that in order to fix it. But it makes sense that you should do it. Once you get to the point where anything you remove, you also remove the bug, that's a [mcve] and that's what you should include in your question.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Well Thank you for your 1st point. I have done as per instruction. I think the rest of stuff is correct and I don't need to remove. I would like to say that I am looking for guideline from this expert community.

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh. But if you don't clean up to the bone, you give people trying to help more work. Most people here come when they're a bit bored. If they see something that's easy for them to fix, they help. If not, they skip to next question. If answering a question means even as much as 10 minutes of cleanup, chances of getting a proper answer go down. Way down.

Comment: I have but one question: what does *"from opposite side"* mean? You want to change the order of the slides? Why not put them in the order you want them in the first place? Can you please explain in a technical way what exactly you want to happen? Example: "*I want the slider to open at last slide and `autoStart` towards the first slide with `infiniteLoop` on.*"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want everything to slide from left to right as opposed to right to left, just replace all occurrences of `goToNextSlide()` with `goToPrevSlide()`. You may need to re-order your images in your HTML but it's easier to do that than tangle with a library.